# datatables initialise DOM and API

Tags: javascript, dom, datatables

I am using DataTables and searched around to find ways to change number of entries shown (default is 10 entries), and how to use DOM to rearrange the positions of elements around the table.

My first issue is, I am not sure how to run datatables API and DOM in single initialisation.

Individually, both codes work:

DOM

```
$('#datatable').dataTable( {
              "dom": 'tip'
    
          } );
```

And API,

```
 var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();  
 table.page.len( 50 ).draw();
```

The error message:

> DataTables warning: table id=datatable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

If someone can direct me how to write this code in a single initialisation.

I also noticed, after I make any attempt with DOM, the pagination element moved down and leaves a gap between the element and the table? What is causing this to happen, and how can I avoid this? Shown on screenshot.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAjC9.png)

Many Thanks

Comment: Regarding your "_pagination element moved down_" question: You should ask that as a separate question (try to only ask one question per question, here on Stack Overflow) - but also provide a [mre] when you do so, so that we can recreate the specific problem you are seeing.

Comment: thank you andrew, I will create a separate question

Answer (score 0):

You can set the page length to 50 records per page as follows:

```js
$('#datatable').dataTable( {
  dom: 'tip',
  pageLength: 50
} );
```

Reference: [`pageLength`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength)

---

Regarding your sample code:

```js
var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();  
table.page.len( 50 ).draw();
```

That works for me. So, you would need to provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which recreates the specific error you are getting.

Here is a demo, which sets the page length to 3 rows per page, using your approach:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();
  table.page.len(3).draw();

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="datatable" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office in Country</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ashton Cox</td>
          <td>Junior "Technical" Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2009/01/12</td>
          <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
          <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2012/03/29</td>
          <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Airi Satou</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>33</td>
          <td>2008/11/28</td>
          <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2012/12/02</td>
          <td>$372,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2012/08/06</td>
          <td>$137,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>55</td>
          <td>2010/10/14</td>
          <td>$327,900</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>39</td>
          <td>2009/09/15</td>
          <td>$205,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sonya Frost</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2008/12/13</td>
          <td>$103,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michael Bruce</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>2011/06/27</td>
          <td>$183,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Donna Snider</td>
          <td>Customer Support</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>2011/01/25</td>
          <td>$112,000</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```